# Eclipse - how to pass VM arguments from command line (without changing eclipse.ini)

Tags: eclipse, command-line-arguments, p2-director

How to pass VM arguments from command line to eclipse?

I am trying to use eclipse [p2 director](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fp2_director.html) to install plugin into Eclipse, but it get's slow and tries to search on download.eclipse.org

There is notice on help page that says:

> While doing these operations, you can disable the automatic mirror selection mechanism by setting the VM argument eclipse.p2.mirrors to false.

Searching over I got ["Why Eclipse’s “Check for Updates” is horribly slow (and how to fix it)"](http://www.vijayp.ca/blog/2011/09/why-eclipses-check-for-updates-is-horribly-slow-and-how-to-fix-it/)

> Add it after “eclipse”, or in eclipse.ini
>   -Declipse.p2.mirrors=false

However

```
eclipsec -Declipse.p2.mirrors=false -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -repository http://www.nodeclipse.org/updates/ -installIU org.nodeclipse.jjs.feature.feature.group/0.10.0
```

-> uknown option

```
eclipsec -vmargs -Declipse.p2.mirrors=false -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -repository http://www.nodeclipse.org/updates/ -installIU org.nodeclipse.jjs.feature.feature.group/0.10.0
```

-> starts workbench

```
eclipsec -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -repository http://www.nodeclipse.org/updates/ -installIU org.nodeclipse.jjs.feature.feature.group/0.10.0 -vmargs -Declipse.p2.mirrors=false
```

-> putting in the end has no effect

Update: I could not succeed with installing, so I thought the reason was that p2 director searches on `download.eclipse.org` and fails. Then after Greg advice, I was sure where those arguments were to be and played with version (It only passes with exact version:
empty or `0.10.0.qualifier` will not suit). So now installation finishes with success but still very slow, maybe because `download.eclipse.org` is still contacted. Log below

`eclipsec -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -repository http://www.nodeclipse.org/updates/ -installIU org.nodeclipse.jjs.feature.feature.group/0.10.0.201401270634 -vmargs -Declipse.p2.mirrors=false`

using eclipse from ATD-Bundle

```
D:\Android\eclipse>r -repository http://www.nodeclipse.org/updates/ -installIU org.nodeclipse.jjs.feature.feature.group/0.10.0.201401270634 -vmargs -Declipse.p2.mirrors=false
Їхт 05, 2014 7:17:31 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
INFO: I/O exception (org.apache.commons.httpclient.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request: The server download.eclipse.org failed to respond
Їхт 05, 2014 7:17:31 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
INFO: Retrying request
Їхт 05, 2014 7:17:39 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
INFO: I/O exception (org.apache.commons.httpclient.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request: The server download.eclipse.org failed to respond
Їхт 05, 2014 7:17:39 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
INFO: Retrying request
Installing org.nodeclipse.jjs.feature.feature.group 0.10.0.201401270634.
Їхт 05, 2014 7:18:10 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
INFO: I/O exception (org.apache.commons.httpclient.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request: The server download.eclipse.org failed to respond
Їхт 05, 2014 7:18:10 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
INFO: Retrying request
Їхт 05, 2014 7:18:20 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
INFO: I/O exception (org.apache.commons.httpclient.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request: The server download.eclipse.org failed to respond
Їхт 05, 2014 7:18:20 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
INFO: Retrying request
Їхт 05, 2014 7:18:31 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
INFO: I/O exception (org.apache.commons.httpclient.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request: The server download.eclipse.org failed to respond
Їхт 05, 2014 7:18:31 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
INFO: Retrying request
Operation completed in 78172 ms.
```

Comment: The end is the correct place. How do you know putting it at the end has no effect?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how the updated answer is related to the original question at all. You should rather start a new question.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was solved long ago, but I have overlooked to share.

What now works inside [Nodeclipse CLI Installer](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/tree/master/org.nodeclipse.ui/templates) is putting VM args in the end:

`nci i markdown
Nodeclipse CLI Installer (nci , Eclipse Plugin Manager epm)
http://www.nodeclipse.org/updates/
starting eclipsec -nosplash -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -repository http://www.nodeclipse.org/updates/ -installIU markdown.editor.feature.feature.group -tag markdown.editor.feature.feature.group -vmargs -Declipse.p2.mirrors=false`